# Symfony database password

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I got a project to fix somethings and when I cant to connect in my database, i changed the .env file to:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://casino_db:DBPASSWORD@127.0.0.1:3306/casino_ordering"
```

but I still have the same problem "An exception occurred in the driver:

```
 SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'casino_db'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

I thing that i need to change some var in the code, may be the the APP_SECRET too?
I cant find where i can change this password

Comment: You need to find out the password used for the user account `casino_db` or you need to reset it, surley you have Admin (root) access to the mysql server you added this database to, so use that to set that password to whatever was in the position you now have `DBPASSWORD` in

Comment: As a note: If your password has special characters, you should url encode it. Eg. `8fi&df3?£^&?` would be `8fi%26df3%3F%C2%A3%5E%26%3F`.

Answer (score 3):

If the password has special characters, you need to url encode it. When url encoding it, you will get a lot of "%" signs that Symfony will try to parse, so you need to escape the "%" with an additional "%".

For example:

- Original password: 1234567890$!*
- URL encoded: 1234567890%24%21%2A
- With % escaped: 1234567890%%24%%21%%2A

So, what goes into your .env file is 1234567890%%24%%21%%2A

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can go wrong.

I suggest you starting with `bin/console debug:dotenv -e <your env>` to check whether the env var is set.